# Spring, 1 form 2 entities

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to save 2 x `entity`, `author` and `book` from a single form. How I can do this?

I know I must first save author, but I don't know how. `Author` is in a one-to-many relationship with `book`.

I have set `cascadetype.ALL`. I'm using thymeleaf.

```html
<form th:object="${book}" th:action="@{/book/}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <label>title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{title}"/>
    <label>isbn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{isbn}"/>
    <label>description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{description}"/>
    <label>cat</label>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="category : ${book.getCategorySet()}" th:text="category.getCategory()"></li>
    </ul>
    <label>author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{author.name}"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

**authorCommand**

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthorCommand {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private Set<BookCommand> bookCommandSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**bookCommand**

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookCommand {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String isbn;
    private String description;
    private Set<CategoryCommand> categorySet = new HashSet<>();
    private AuthorCommand author;
}
```

**bookController**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "book/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newBook(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("book", new BookCommand());
    return "book/form";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "book", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute("book") BookCommand bookCommand){
    BookCommand savedBook = bookService.saveBookCommand(bookCommand);
    return "redirect:/book/show/"+savedBook.getId();
}
```

Comment: You basically have two options: 1) create the author first, i.e. use 2 forms and only allow the user to select an existing author for a new book or 2) handle new/unknown authors in your controller, especially when the autor's id is unknown (`long` can't be null so "unknown" must be represented by some other value, e.g. -1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can always send additional parameters aside from your model, using the `name` tag in your inputs.

**HTML**

```
<form th:object="${book}" th:action="@{/book/}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <label>title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{title}"/>
    <label>isbn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{isbn}"/>
    <label>description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{description}"/>
    <label>cat</label>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="category : ${book.getCategorySet()}" th:text="category.getCategory()"></li>
    </ul>
    <label>author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "book", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute("book") BookCommand bookCommand,
                           @RequestParam("author") String name,
                           BindingResult bindingResult){
    if( bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/book/new";
    }

    Author author = new Author();
    author.setName(name);
    authorService.saveAuthor(author);
    savedBook.setAuthor(author);
    BookCommand savedBook = bookService.saveBookCommand(bookCommand);
    return "redirect:/book/show/"+savedBook.getId();
}
```

A few things to considered, I don't know how you are separating the author name, but I would add two different inputs, one for the first name and another for the last name. Also, I am assuming the author's id is using `@GeneratedValue`.

Comment: When I try your solve, I got error : Validation failed for object='book'. Error count: 1

Comment: Yes, author's id is using @generatedvalue

Comment: Are you validating your entity? If you are validating your book entity and you are expecting your author to be not null, your binding will fail.